# Access Service in more than one component

Tags: angular, ionic4

I wrote a service and now I want one Instance over the complete app. Therefore I added the service in the app module under Providers.

In more than one component I inject the service in the "constructor".

```
     constructor(public btSlotService: BTSlotService ) {
    this.slotitems = this.btSlotService.getSlotItems();
  }
```

In the service I have a console.log in the contructor and I see now that the constructor is called more than once.

Comment: By default angular will have injected containers as singletons unless you have lazy loaded modules.

Comment: Here is docs which specify when you can get more then one instance https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#injector-hierarchy-and-service-instances

Comment: That shouldn't be the case. Can you replicate this in a Sample StackBlitz and share it across? You can check [this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-angular4-bmqdnf) out. It does exactly what you're saying but doesn't log things twice to the console.

Answer (score 0):

Oh Sorry, all works fine. I used "ionic lab" and this list both apps ios and android and therefore the log comes twice because I switched on both apps to the same page.